# Should you use the form class?

Tags: c#

I am quite new to programming and want to make sure I am doing things the "industry standard" way as it normally is the best way. I am about to start my second project and had a quick question about how I should design the program. I have thought about it and decided that the program only needs one class to run, the problem I have is if I should use the form class or make another class? I don't know why I think this might be a bad thing, I just feel it could be.

For example is it ok to put my functions into the "public partial class mainForm : Form" class?

EDIT : I think people are confusing me a bit, I simply want to put some buttons on a form and such - should I put all the actual code i.e. functions that do the actual computing within the forms class or should I make another class and then call myClass.function?

Comment: If the code in your form is not going to be used anywhere else I would just leave it there. Read a little bit about Separation of concerns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: The reason you want to use the `Form` class is to inherit its behaviors (being a Windows form, namely).  And yes, separation of concerns is mandatory reading. :)

Comment: I don't know about the "Industry standard", but if you're concerned with good code quality, you'd rather stay away from winforms and use newer technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any gain from creating class inherited from Form class just "to do things right" (unless you are talking about self-generated code, which in that case inherits from Form class). If there's no point of inheritance don't use it. In case of windows forms if you create new project your form automatically inherits from Form. Don't try to overthink your project, you'll know how to do things right when time comes - it's a matter of experience. Right now, just do as you think you should do, read a lot and make mistakes! You'll learn in time how the project should look like.

So good luck and have fun coding!

Comment: I think he means that he's putting his functions in the `Form` class that was generated when he created his WinForms application. It generates a partial class, one for the actual form, and one for the code behind it.

Comment: I think people are confusing me a bit, I simply want to put some buttons on a form and such - should I put all the actual code i.e. functions that do the actual computing within the forms class or should I make another class and then call myClass.function?

Comment: I try to stick to the rule KISS - Keep It Simple, Stupid. If you don't need to create another class, don't do it. You'll learn about such things as IoC and Dependency Injection and such later on, then you might create classes just to put methods in them, right now it's useless. You should find some tutorial on google (maybe look for it at codeproject.com) and follow it to do your project. And don't hesitate to make mistakes! You'll learn from yours certainly :)

Comment: Ah great stuff, this is what I needed to know - thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

WinForm?

For simple utils go with the form, for anything more hardcore I'd recommend starting with a service object that configures and glues things together. Then you can do:

```
Application.Run(applicationObjectThatIMadeEarlier.InitialForm);
```

To get back to where you're used to being.

WinForm constructors can be iffy because of the form designer requirements (it runs the ctor) so its nice to keep things out of the constructor of a WinForm so the form designers keep working.

Answer (score 0):

Generally spoken, yes. As long as you only have one class - in this case your form - and the functions won't be required anywhere else outside of the form.

Is it good practice? Well, not really. Sooner or later you'll be working on projects that don't consist of one class or one form and you'll be sticking all your functions in your form, only to figure out later down the line that you'll need them elsewhere too.

In this specific case you could do it, but I'd personally recommend you to put them in their own class(es).

Comment: Ok great thanks! The application I want to make does some stuff with steam, would you say this is an appropriate way to design it? http://pastebin.com/gA6cepzT

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, if that's all the code you have I wouldn't bother making it more complicated than it needs to be.